Add azureSubscription in a "each" loop
I need to add the azureSubscription to my each loop which looks like this
parameters:
- name: info
   displayName: Information
   type: object
   default:
     info1: abc
     info2: 123
     info3: hello
steps:
  - checkout: none
  - ${{ each info in parameters.info }}:
      - script: |
          echo "info1 is ${{ info.info1}}"
          echo "info2 is ${{ info.info2}}"
          echo "info3 is ${{ info.info3}}"

          az keyvault secret set --vault-name ${{ parameters.info1 }} --name ${{ parameters.info2 }} --value ${{ parameters.info3 }}
        displayName: Show ${{ info.key }} value

I tried adding it as an input and tried adding it without input but I get an unexpected parameter error
parameters:
 - name: info
   displayName: Information
   type: object
   default:
     info1: abc
     info2: 123
     info3: hello
steps:
  - checkout: none
  - ${{ each info in parameters.info }}:
      -   inputs:
           azureSubscription: subscriptionNumber
          script: |
          echo "info1 is ${{ info.info1}}"
          echo "info2 is ${{ info.info2}}"
          echo "info3 is ${{ info.info3}}"

          az keyvault secret set --vault-name ${{ parameters.info1 }} --name ${{ parameters.info2 }} --value ${{ parameters.info3 }}
        displayName: Show ${{ info.key }} value`


Do you need to update one or more keyvault secrets?

It'll be at least 2 Key Vault secrets mostly each time

You can set an array of objects containing the keyvault secrets you want to update and then use ${{ each ... }} to generate a script task for each one.
Also, consider using --output none so that you don't accidentally output the secret value in the pipeline logs:
az keyvault secret set .... --output none

Changing your code slightly to make it more readable:
parameters:
  - name: secrets
    displayName: Keyvault secrets
    type: object
    default:
      - subscription: my-subscription1
        vaultName: my-keyvault1
        secretName: my-secret1
        secretValue: password123
      - subscription: my-subscription2
        vaultName: my-keyvault2
        secretName: my-secret2
        secretValue: password456

steps:
  - checkout: none
  - ${{ each secret in parameters.secrets }}:
    - script: |
        echo "Subscription: ${{ secret.subscription }}"
        echo "Vault name: ${{ secret.vaultName }}"
        echo "Secret name: ${{ secret.secretName }}"
        
        # DO NOT PRINT SECRET VALUE IN THE PIPELINE LOGS
        # echo "Secret value: ${{ secret.secretValue }}"

        # ECHO USED JUST FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES, REPLACE WITH ACTUAL COMMAND
        echo "az keyvault secret set --subscription ${{ secret.subscription }} --vault-name ${{ secret.vaultName }} --name ${{ secret.secretName }} --value ${{ secret.secretValue }} --output none"
      displayName: 'Set secret ${{ secret.vaultName }}/${{ secret.secretName }}'

Running the pipeline:

EDIT 1
Using an AzureCLI@2 task instead of script:
parameters:
  - name: secrets
    displayName: Keyvault secrets
    type: object
    default:
      - subscription: my-subscription1
        vaultName: my-keyvault1
        secretName: my-secret1
        secretValue: password123
      - subscription: my-subscription2
        vaultName: my-keyvault2
        secretName: my-secret2
        secretValue: password456

steps:
  - ${{ each secret in parameters.secrets }}:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: ${{ secret.subscription }} # name of Azure DevOps service connection
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          az keyvault secret set --vault-name ${{ secret.vaultName }} --name ${{ secret.secretName }} --value ${{ secret.secretValue }} --output none"
      displayName: 'Set secret ${{ secret.vaultName }}/${{ secret.secretName }}'


Thank you! Took note of the edit as well

If you want to use multiple service connections to deploy to multiple resource groups and update multiple Key Vaults or secrets, it's suggested to use nested object parameter. So that you can avoid providing the same values in the parameter and short the parameter.
parameters:
- name: info
  displayName: Information
  type: object
  default:
  - subName: Sub1
    kvs:
    - kvName: kv1
      secretName: kv1s1
      secretValue: 1
    - kvName: kv2
      secretName: kv2s1
      secretValue: 1
  - subName: Sub2
    kvs:
    - kvName: kv3
      secretName: kv3s1
      secretValue: 1

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- ${{ each sub in parameters.info }}:
  - ${{ each keyvault in sub.kvs }}:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: Using Sub ${{sub.subName}}
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: ${{sub.subName}}
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: 'az keyvault secret set --name ${{keyvault.secretName}} --vault-name ${{keyvault.kvName}} --value ${{keyvault.secretValue}}'


In the above yaml, three different Azure KeyVaults in two resource groups are updated. If you have many secrets in one KeyVault to update, you can nest the secrets in KeyVault and loop through each secret in Azure CLI.

Hi @eliew, it's great to know it works for you. Do you have any other question or need any other help related to nested object parameter?

Hello @ziyang Liu-MSFT, I don't have another question. Thank you for your help!
